# Select a field in an array inside mongodb and display only unique field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Will need select a field in an array inside mongodb.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53dbb05fa976627439d43884"),
"employee" : [ 
    {
        "dateJoin" : "1986-03-10",
        "deptName" : "x",

    }, 
    {
        "dateJoin" : "1986-12-11",
        "deptName" : "y",

    },
 {
        "dateJoin" : "1986-12-11",
        "deptName" : "y",

    }
 ]
 }
```

In my case I would like select all the unique deptName available. The output is something like below.

```
  { deptName:x,
   deptName:y }
```

So far I have tried the below command but no luck.

```
db.employee.find( {},{ employee.deptName:1})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation framework is probably your way, but if you just wan the distinct values across the collection there is the [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method:

```js
db.collection.distinct("employee.deptName")
```

Which outputs :

```js
 ["x","y"]
```

Alternately with the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) just do:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$employee" },
    { "$group": { "_id": "employee.deptName" } }
])
```

Which outputs:

```js
{ "_id" : "y" }
{ "_id" : "x" }
```

Or the same thing as a single document result:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$employee" },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "deptName": { "$addToSet": "$employee.deptName" }
    }}
])
```

Which outputs:

```js
{ "_id" : null, "deptName" : [ "y", "x" ] }
```

Or if you actually want this per document, then like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$employee" },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "deptName": { "$addToSet": "$employee.deptName" }
    }}
])
```

For this:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53dbb05fa976627439d43884"), "deptName" : [ "y", "x" ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, on your case, this is not a simple query but an aggregation query. If I remember that :

```
db.employee.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind : '$employee'
    }
    {
        $group : {
            _id : {
                id : '$_id',
                deptName : '$employee.deptName'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            _id : '$_id.id',
            deptName : '$_id.deptName'
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : '$_id',
            deptName : { $addToSet : '$deptName' }
        }
    }
]);
```

`unwind` is used to unwind your array and generate one record per array items.
`group` is used to group by _id and depName
`project` is used to reorganize out record Line
`group` is used this time to regroup all records and add into An Array all uniqe deptName.

After that you shoud retrive this for all records :

```
{ 
    _id : ObjectId("53dbb05fa976627439d43884"),
    deptName : [ 'x', 'y' ]
}
```

I have not test this aggregate function but, if i remember, it should be works.

Edit : I test that and it works fine

For aggregation, the result is like this :

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("54082a2463a023dbfa7d82fb"),
            "deptName" : [ 
                "x", 
                "y"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Yes that does give the distinct values per document. But you went a really long way around to get here. This is actually much more simple than you present it.

Comment: You've right, i complexify my aggregation request for nothing